# Show only single record from multiple entries on the same date with different time

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following sample data:

```
|UserID|DateTime           |
| 1    |2019-01-01 11:30:00|
| 1    |2019-01-01 12:30:00|
| 2    |2019-01-01 10:35:00|
| 2    |2019-01-01 11:45:00|
| 3    |2019-01-01 12:36:01|
| 3    |2019-01-01 14:23:12|
| 1    |2019-01-02 11:12:11|
| 2    |2019-01-02 11:30:12|
| 2    |2019-01-02 12:12:00|
| 3    |2019-01-02 10:14:00|
| 3    |2019-01-02 11:00:00|
```

Expecting the following query output:

```
|UserID|DateTime           |
| 1    |2019-01-01 11:30:00|
| 2    |2019-01-01 10:35:00|
| 3    |2019-01-01 12:36:01|
| 1    |2019-01-02 11:12:11|
| 2    |2019-01-02 11:30:12|
| 3    |2019-01-02 10:14:00|
```

I know `SELECT DISTINCT` should be a good start but since it's involving a date-time column I have no idea where to start.

**SOLVED**

Using DarkRob's suggestion:

```
SELECT UserID, MIN(DateTime) AS DATE FROM targettable GROUP BY UserID, CONVERT(varchar(10), DateTime, 23)
```

Note that I use CONVERT instead of CAST as it will throw an error when running on MSSQL2005

Comment: what is the logic here ? Can you explain ?

Comment: Hi Squirrel,it is a attendance application.User where allow to 'punch-in' how many times as they like,but record will taken on the first entry only.

Comment: first entry of the day ? what if there are multiple `in-out` in a day ?

Comment: In and out on different site/machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
select UserId, Min(datetime) as Datetime
from [table]
group by UserId, Cast(datetime as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window functions and write query as given below

```
SELECT UserID, DateTime
FROM
(
    SELECT UserID, DataTime
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY DateTime) AS rnk
    FROM Table1
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```